# AngularJS: set target (similar to focus) to any $scope property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a layout with multiple elements which are able to gain target. I need to target only one element at the time.
Is it possible to define a function on the $scope that receives an object from the model (for example a line item belonging to an invoice) and tell Angular to add a css class wherever the view of this model is?

If I use the ng-class directive, it would force me to add ng-class to all "targetable" elements in the html and each element should know if it is the current target or not. I don't want to add an isTarget() function to each possible element because it will dirty the model.

Example:
This is the html:

```
<p>{{document.shipFrom}}</p>
<p>{{document.shipTo}}</p>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in document.items">{{item.description}}</li>
</ul>
```

And this is the controller:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('DocumentCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.document = {
        shipFrom: 'Origin',
        shipTo: 'Destination',
        items: [
            {description:'item1'},
            {description:'item2'}
        ]
    };
})
```

Is there a way to define $scope.setTarget($scope.document.items[0]) so that it adds a class "on-target" to the element? Note that all the document properties (the items and the shipFrom/To) can gain target.

### Edit: Solved

I found a way to get a model's attribute value in my directive's linking function. If I use the [$parse](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$parse) service then I can evaluate the model's property attached to the directive simply by instantiating a getter function:

```
link: function postLink ($scope, $iElement, $iAttrs) {
    var valueGetter = $parse($iAttrs.ngModel);

    //Then, I can subscribe the directive to a custom event:
    $scope.$on('set.target', function (event, elem) {
        $iElement.removeClass('on-target alert-info');
        //Now it gets the actual value of the model related to the directive
        var value = valueGetter($scope);
        //If both the model and the event's value are the same, then focus the element.
        if (value == elem) {
            $iElement.addClass('on-target alert-info');
            $scope.setTarget(valueName, elem);
            $scope.$apply();
    }
    return;
    });
}//end link function
```

When I need something to gain target from the controller, then I just do `$scope.$broadcast('set.target', $scope.document.shipFrom)`

Answer (score 0):

HTML Part :

```
<p>{{document.shipFrom}}</p>
<p>{{document.shipTo}}</p>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in document.items" ng-click="setTarget(item.description)" ng-class="{'active' : selectedTarget == item.description}">{{item.description}}</li>
</ul>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.document = {
    shipFrom: 'Origin',
    shipTo: 'Destination',
    items: [
        {description:'item1'},
        {description:'item2'}
    ]
};

$scope.selectedTarget = '';  

$scope.setTarget = function(data) {
  $scope.selectedTarget = data;  
};
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EsnD4/)

Comment: Thanks, but I found a way to appy target to all the elements from the model, not just the items, without defining ng-click and ng-class conditions. See my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add an isTarget() function to each possible item, you could add isTarget method on document.

```
isTarget: function(item){
  return this.target === item;
}
```

and change the html to

```
<li ng-repeat="item in document.items" ng-class="{'on-target': document.isTarget(item)}">{{item.description}}</li>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I found a way to appy target to all the elements from the model, not just the items, without defining ng-click and ng-class conditions. See my updated question.